# Добавить запись в БД. Название фотографий с папки

Tags: php, sql, файлы, insert

```
function can_upload($file){

    // если имя пустое, значит файл не выбран
      if($file['name'] == '')
      return 'Вы не выбрали файл.';

    /* если размер файла 0, значит его не пропустили настройки 
    сервера из-за того, что он слишком большой */
    if($file['size'] == 0)
      return 'Файл слишком большой.';

    // разбиваем имя файла по точке и получаем массив
    $getMime = explode('.', $file['name']);
    print_r($getMime);
    // нас интересует последний элемент массива - расширение
    $mime = strtolower(end($getMime));
    // объявим массив допустимых расширений
    $types = array('jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp', 'jpeg');

    copy($file['tmp_name'], 'img/'.$file['name']);
    $ava = 'img/'.$file['name'];
    $results = $db->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`ava`) VALUES('123')");
    if($results) {
      echo 'true';
    } else {
      echo 'false';
    }
    // если расширение не входит в список допустимых - return
    if(!in_array($mime, $types))
      return 'Недопустимый тип файла.';

    return true;
    }


  // если была произведена отправка формы
  if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    // проверяем, можно ли загружать изображение
    $check = can_upload($_FILES['file']);

    if($check === true){
      // загружаем изображение на сервер
      echo "<strong>Файл успешно загружен!</strong>";
    }
    else{
      // выводим сообщение об ошибке
      echo "<strong>$check</strong>";  
    }
  }
```

Не получается занести в бд название картинки. Ошибку выводит Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in  в этой строке $results = $db->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`ava`) VALUES('123')"); Хотя я сделал самый простой запрос. Хотел бы уточнить у меня в бд несколько строк и у всех пустые столбцы `ava`. И к тому же у меня сессия, пользователь авторизован может мне надо добавить where в какой столбец я должен добавить запись?

Answer (score 0):

Решено: Изменил запрос на UPDATE ... SET

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка `Call to a member function query() on null` говорит о том, что вы применяете функцию `query()` к какому-то необъявленному объекту (в вашем случае – к переменной `$db`).

Вероятно, переменная `$db` объявлена вне функции `can_upload()`, и из этой функции данная переменная не видна.

В начале функции укажите использование глобальной переменной `$db`:

```
global $db;
```

Также рекомендую ознакомиться с статьёй: [Область видимости переменной](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php).